# No disks were found on which to perform cluster validation tests

Tags: hyper-v, cluster, windows-server-2012, storage-area-network

I am trying to make a cluster of two Hyper-V machines running Windows Server 2012.

There is a SAN available in which I have created several partitions to use such as J drive, K drive L drive etc.

All these drives are available as network share and mapped on both machines.

The primary hard disk of both machines is C drive.

When I run Cluster Validation Wizard it throws warning for several file/disk related operations such as:

**Validate Disk Access Latency**
No disks were found on which to perform cluster validation tests

**Validate Disk Arbitration**
No disks were found on which to perform cluster validation tests
How do I fix this warning?

Comment: I don't believe that mapped network drives are valid cluster storage.

Comment: How do you propose I do it?

Comment: What kind of SAN is it, iSCSI or FC? Create a LUN on the SAN. connect the Hyper-V hosts to the LUN. Create a CSV. - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj612868.aspx

Comment: Mapped drives (also called SMB shares) are valid cluster storage, as long as the SMB server is capable of SMB 3.0 or later.  But you still won't see any "disks" in the cluster wizard, as you're not presenting disks to the cluster, you're presenting a network share.